# How to set background image url both for hover and non-hover behaviors of a list item dynamically?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a requirement where in the user can create new list items inspite of having default list items. So The user will be allowed to attach two icon images for the list items to show on hover of list item and on non hover of list item. So, now I want to change the background image to the given URL's in the property of the object that is iterated in ng-repeat. I have been trying using jquery to get the property and its value but couldn't replace with the hover_image URL from the object on hover.

```
<ul id="user_events_list" class="listing_categories" ng-repeat="event in privateEventItems">
    <li class="eventListItem" style="background-image :url('{{event.eventIconUrl}}'); background-position:10px; background-repeat : no-repeat; padding-left:30px;">{{event.eventName}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to change the `{{event.eventIconUrl}}` to `{{event.eventHoverIconUrl}}` on mouse hover on the list item. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave` events.

```
<ul id="user_events_list" class="listing_categories" ng-repeat="event in privateEventItems">
    <li class="eventListItem" ng-init="anyChosenVariableNameForUrls=event.eventIconUrl"
        style="background-image :url('{{anyChosenVariableNameForUrls}}'); background-position:10px; background-repeat : no-repeat; padding-left:30px;"
        ng-mouseenter="anyChosenVariableNameForUrls=event.eventHoverIconUrl"
        ng-mouseleave="anyChosenVariableNameForUrls=event.eventIconUrl"
    >{{event.eventName}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... It actually worked as expected... You saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('#name img').hover(function() {
  $(this).attr('src', 'https://developers.google.com/maps/images/lhimages/api/icon_placesapi.svg');
}, function() {
  $(this).attr('src', 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/web-2/256/Google-icon.png');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="name">
    <img title="Hello" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/web-2/256/Google-icon.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: jQuery solution is not suitable here. It should be done angular-way.

Comment: I wanted the url's to be dynamic not the static ones... thankyou for your response :)..

Answer (score 0):

To do it in angular way see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcp9nsjw/1/)

use `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseleave` directives to detect mouse hover and leave.